# Homemade cream cheese

Tags: cheese, cheesecake, cheese-making, cream-cheese

I like to make no bake cheese cake when I checked few blogs and I got to know that cream cheese is important for this but I don't have cream cheese in the nearby shops. When I further started searching I saw one more blog where they used yogurt and crumbled paneer which is easy for me to use. I just wanted to know is that both together is cream cheese or it's something different.

Answer (score 5):

Cream cheese is a distinct product, with a flavour and texture of its own.

I don't think you'd get the right texture by crumbling paneer into yoghurt, but if you can make paneer you can make cream cheese - or rather [an easy form of ricotta] (https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2016/nov/14/homemade-ricotta-recipe-anna-jones-modern-cook) , which is a type of acid set cream cheese. It's essentially the same as making paneer but you stop short of boiling the milk before adding the lemon juice, and you don't press it after straining. If you can make or get unpressed paneer that might work.

Mascarpone is thicker and richer, made from fresh double (heavy) cream and lemon juice.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for your help and yes I can get unpressed paneer from milk I can make it. If so I can use that for cream cheese cake right?

Comment: If it has a mild flavour and can be stirred together with the other ingredients, it should be suitable for a cheesecake

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't find cream cheese when I lived in Korea in the 1990's. This is what I did.  Get cream that is at least 18% butter fat or higher. Ferment with yogurt cultures, 3 to 5 days the same as yogurt.  Salt it, about 1/2 gram per 100 ml. Then drain it using a coffee filter or cheese cloth for one to two days.. To get the desired consistency it may need to be pressed. 
  If you can get rennet, there are recipes to make proper french cream cheese. But if you can't get cream cheese, rennet is even more difficult to find. cheesemaking.com has a lot of information on making different types of cheeses